# vim add automatical sphinx comment under function and class definition

Tags: python, vim

I want to automatically add sphinx comment under head functions and classes.
When I press Enter after head function or class, comment could be implemented like this:

```
def func(a): #<Enter>
    """
    Args:
       a (type):  The name to use.

    Returns:
       type.  The return
    """
```

Is it possible to configure .vimrc (.vimrc.local)? Do you know command for this? Or may be plugin?

Comment: Well… did *you* look for a plugin or try something before asking? That's typically what Snippet expansion plugins like Snipmate or Ultisnips do.

Comment: @romainl: Thank's but after installing it when i type `main` for example the list of template main appears for autocompletion but when i type <tab> it doesn't autocomplete.

Comment: "it" is the snippet in python.snippets. For example I type def in a test.py file and <tab> but nothing happen. Or #! which add encoding.
May be the problem come from mode mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though you can do this with the built-in (insert-mode) *mappings*, you'll soon want to do more advanced insertions.

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3aAutomated_Text_Insertion).

There are two things to evaluate: First, the features of the snippet engine itself, and second, the quality and breadth of snippets provided by the author or others.

Comment: I'd add a third thing to evaluate: how easy it is to add your own snippets.

Comment: @romainl: Okay, though what I've seen so far is pretty similar: Some custom `:Snippet` command or a DSL in a separate file. There are differences with escaping, naturally, but it's usually straightforward.